# How to Replace values of a property in an Array Object with values of a property in another Array Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have an Array Object

```
    const admins= [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Admin 1',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Admin 2',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Admin 3',
    }
]
```

and another Array Object

```
const members= [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name 1',
        addedByAdminId: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Name 2',
        addedByAdminId: 2
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Name 3',
        addedByAdminId: 3
    }
]
```

I want to replace values of addedByAdminId of member arrayObject by names of admins where admins.id = addedByAdminId

My Current Code :

`const objectC = members.forEach((item) => item.addedByAdminId= admins.filter(obj => obj.id === item.addedByAdminId)[0]['name']);`

Expected Result :

```
objectC = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name 1',
        addedByAdminId: 'Admin 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Name 2',
        addedByAdminId: 'Admin 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Name 3',
        addedByAdminId: 'Admin 3'
    }
]
```

Error I am Getting :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

I am using React.

Comment: It worked for me. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/b38y6paf/7/).
Note: `forEach` returns `undefined`, so your `objectC` is undefined, and `members` is modified in-place

Comment: Check this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/gOeZdEE

Comment: Thank you very much... I understood what the problem was.

Comment: I assume that your code is not working because you are modifying the same array "members" while searching on it using "members.filter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is what you want to do:**

```js
const newMembers = members.map(member => {
    // get the admin name
    const adminName = admins.find(it => it.id === member.addedByAdminId)?.name;
    // create a new object with the spread operator
    // containing everything from the memmber object 
    // overriding the property addedByAdminId with the variable adminName
    return {...member, addedByAdminId: adminName}
});
```

Result

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name 1",
        "addedByAdminId": "Admin 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Name 2",
        "addedByAdminId": "Admin 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Name 3",
        "addedByAdminId": "Admin 3"
    }
]
```

**But this is what i suggest:**
Instead of overriding a variable with a value that doesn't match this variable name just create a new one.

Code:

```js
const newMembers = members.map(member => {
    const adminName = admins.find(it => it.id === member.addedByAdminId)?.name;
    return {...member, addedByAdminName: adminName}
});
```

Result

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name 1",
        "addedByAdminId": 1,
        "addedByAdminName": "Admin 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Name 2",
        "addedByAdminId": 2,
        "addedByAdminName": "Admin 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Name 3",
        "addedByAdminId": 3,
        "addedByAdminName": "Admin 3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

So like this?

```js
const admins = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Admin 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Admin 2',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Admin 3',
  }
]

const members = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name 1',
    addedByAdminId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Name 2',
    addedByAdminId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Name 3',
    addedByAdminId: 3
  }
]

const objC = members.map(({ id, name, addedByAdminId }) => ({
  id,
  name,
  addedByAdminId: admins[addedByAdminId - 1].name
}))

console.log(objC)
```

Comment: this code works when both arrays are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

this will replace addedByAdminId with the name when a matching record is present in admin array. if there is no matching record found to the addedByAdminId, the addedByAdminId will be not replaced.

```
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Admin 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Admin 2',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Admin 3',
  }
]

const members = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name 1',
    addedByAdminId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Name 2',
    addedByAdminId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Name 3',
    addedByAdminId: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Name 4',
    addedByAdminId: 4
  }
]

const result = members.map(({ id, name, addedByAdminId }) => ({
  id,
  name,
  addedByAdminId: admins.some(admin => admin.id === addedByAdminId) ? admins.find(admin => admin.id === addedByAdminId).name : addedByAdminId
}))

console.log(result);
```